# Use one method to all messages from db

Tags: php, mysql, regex, laravel

I have a tables which I want to use one or more methods to all result from db. This method can change #hashtags to links, bbcode to html tags, etc. Let's assume that I have this query:

```
$query = Comments::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comments table has a comment column where user can use emoticons bbcode, etc. This query returns a few of results. How I can use method on column? If I have one result is simple:

```
$query = Posts::find(1);
$desc = myMethod($query->desc);
```

Comment: I did not understand what are you trying to do

Comment: If you get multiple results/rows you need to loop over the results and call your function. Or your function accepts an array and iterates over each element. if that's what you are asking

Comment: \Show us the generated `SELECT` SQL statement.

Comment: Could you show any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumne you want to format your eloquent attributes? have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

and if you don't want to save your formatted data on db. you can just use the Accessor by defining it. for example please see below

```
// on your model you just need to create new methods 
// with `get` as prefix and `Attribute` as suffix

public function getBbcToHtmlAttribute() {
    return myMethod($query->desc);
}
```

please note that `get` and `Attribute` on your method name is required (e.g getMyNewAccessorAttribute`

after that you need to add `casts` property. if you already have casts property you just add it to the array if you dont have casts property you need to define it.

```
protected $casts = [
    'BbcToHtml'
];
```

and then you can use it anywhere on your model instance.

```
$query = Posts::find(1);
$desc = $query->bbctohtml;
```

Comment: It works but not I want. I want to save normal text in my db, like: "#hashtag, [b]something[/b]" but in view I want to display html tags instead of bbcode, emots chars, add links to #hashtags, etc/

Comment: so what is the current data on your database? something like this? ` "#hashtag, [b]something[/b]"`

Comment: Yes. I have values like #hashtag [b]something[/b], etc in my db.

Comment: okay i think what you need now is a bbc parser. you might have a look here.https://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser2

Comment: I don't have a time to read the documentation now but I have my own method to this. It is possible to use this method to my all comments? Maybe some loop or something like that?

Comment: well if you already have a method. you can use it on mutations. 'give me time ill make an example

Comment: OK. When I come back, I look here. If I try use mutation, it save html tag in my database but I want to avoid it and save oryginal text.

Comment: hi i have updated my answer. you can use accesor only if you dont have it to save to your database.

Comment: I have error `Undefined variable: query`. I tryed add `$query` like and attribute but it doesn't works.

Comment: Of course https://pastebin.com/ZjQAaVTS. It will be works in `@foreach` into view? For example `@foreach($posts->comments as $comment) {{ $comment->bbctohtml }} @endforeach`?

Comment: hmmm yeah  for sure. can you dd on `$query` before calling the bbctohtml? and also please move your casts property on the top of all your methods. right below the fillables

Comment: I did that and I have this same error `Undefined variable: query`

Comment: i think that's a different issue now? you can check on `php artisan tinker` if the accessor works

Comment: `App\Comment::find(1)->bbctohtml` return null. This comment exist.

Comment: did you put the casts property at the top of your methods?

Comment: oh yeah i overlook also. on the accessor method. so is this solve you problem? dont forget to accept :)

Answer (score 0):

As MarkB has said, you would need to use a mutator, create a helper class that can take any input and produce the correct html code for your bbcode.  Then you would create a mutator on your model and use that instead of the field where the bbcode text is.